# Unable to get Power BI Token Using AcquireTokenAsync function

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

One of my ASP.NET MVC project uses Power BI report to integrate into the page. In the controller I use this code to get the token.

```
var credential = new UserPasswordCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize/");
var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api", "APPLICATION_ID", credential).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

When the code reach `AcquireTokenAsync` function, it throws this exception. I appreciate your support.

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: unknown_error: Unknown error > System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.HttpClientWrapper.d__30.MoveNext()
> End of inner exception stack trace
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.d__21`1.MoveNext() End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.<GetResponseAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext()
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.d__20`1.MoveNext() End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserRealmDiscoveryResponse.<CreateByDiscoveryAsync>d__24.MoveNext() End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenNonInteractiveHandler.<PreTokenRequest>d__5.MoveNext() End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<RunAsync>d__55.MoveNext() End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.<AcquireTokenCommonAsync>d__52.MoveNext() End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions.<AcquireTokenAsync>d__0.MoveNext() End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at Manpower.TicketTracking.Web.Areas.TicketsManagement.Controllers.DashboardController.d__15.MoveNext() in D:\DashboardController.cs:line 317
> ErrorCode: unknown_error
> StatusCode: 0

Comment: `ttps://` or `https://`?

Comment: @AndreyNikolov it is `https://`